# Why is the CAGradientLayer removed from view after modal view controller is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I am creating a gradient layer and adding it to my `MainViewController` self.view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.colors = colors
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

}
```

Inside `viewDidAppear` I am enumerating all the sublayers:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for x in (view.layer.sublayers)! {
        print(x)
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I am running the app (which is normal):

```
<CAGradientLayer: 0x608000224120>
<_UILabelLayer: 0x60000009a400>
<_UILabelLayer: 0x60800009f180>
<CALayer: 0x600000422d60>
<CALayer: 0x608000223820>
```

Then from `MainViewController` I present modally another vc and then dismiss it. After this MainVC `viewDidAppear` is called again, but this time I get this:

```
<_UILabelLayer: 0x60000009a400>
<_UILabelLayer: 0x60800009f180>
<CALayer: 0x600000422d60>
<CALayer: 0x608000223820>
```

The `CAGradientLayer` was removed from self.view. I can fix this by moving my code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`, but I want to understand why is the `CAGradientLayer` removed, after the controller was dismissed.

Comment: Did you try printing before calling  `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`?

Comment: Same issue if I print in viewWillAppear

Comment: Did you subclass directly the `UIViewController`?

Comment: How is `gradient` declared? How are you dismissing your modal viewController?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov: yes, I am subclassing UIViewController

Comment: @vacawama: I just call dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: How is `gradient` declared?

Comment: @vacawama:  public var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

Comment: Add `class MyCAGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    deinit {
        print("there it goes")
    }
}
` and replace your `CAGradientLayer()` with `MyCAGradientLayer`.  Set a breakpoint on the print statement to see where it is getting freed.

Comment: its weird, the message is printed before viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear on startup, but I can see it printed in viewDidAppear in my for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142392/discussion-between-vacawama-and-kobe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce your situation in a simple test program.

Here is some debugging advice...

To find out where the gradient layer is being removed from `view.layers`, define

```
class MyCAGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    deinit {
        print("there it goes")
    }
}
```

and replace your `CAGradientLayer` with `MyCAGradientLayer` which is created locally in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gradient = MyCAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.colors = colors
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

After `viewDidLoad` finishes the local variable `gradient` will release its reference to the `gradient` and only one reference to the `gradient` will exist (the one in the `view.layers` array).

Set a breakpoint on the `print` statement to see where it is getting freed.